# В переменную Apple1 и Apple2 указываются числа,как получить Number а не string?

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    alert('Привет!');
    let Ya = prompt('Как тебя зовут?');
    let Friend = prompt(`Как зовут твоего друга?`);
    let apple1 = prompt(`Сколько у вас яблок?`);
    let apple2 = prompt(`Сколько у вашего друга?`);
    let apple3 = apple1 + apple2;
    alert(`Значит ${Ya} и ${Friend} имеют ${apple3} яблок!`);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: let apple3 = +apple1 + +apple2;

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: смотрите способы в ответе дубликате

Answer (score 0):

Приведи apple1 и apple2 явно к типу через parseInt и затем сложи

Comment: Метод пользователя @Dias Мне понравился больше,но спасибо за предложение!